# What is the JavaScript equivalent of { if "a" in "abc" }

Tags: javascript

Hi there I am currently working in a javascript project, though I cam across a problem, I don't know how to check if something is a part of a string. I know you don't understand what that means but to give you a n example of how you would do it in python.

```
if "a" in "abc":
    print("a")
```

How do you do this in js can anyone tell me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if("abc".indexOf("a") > -1){...}`

Comment: you don't know how much time I spend trying to figure this out

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @ScottMarcus Modern JS has [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) now.

Comment: .includes is a closer equivalent and shorter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @Ouroborus Ok, but it's 2 characters shorter. Not earth shattering.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Not sure what that has to do with it. Instead, you're dropping a returned value and a comparison. Not a big deal if you're just using it once but nice to be aware of for larger tasks.

Comment: Thank you everyone for telling me how to solve my problem

Comment: @Ouroborus Those same operations are being performed internally by `includes()`. It's just abstracted away into the method call so you're not saving anything on performance like you think you are. I replied about the characters because you said it's shorter.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sure, but the difference may be that that the abstraction is in a faster implementation. Performance testing would sus out the difference, if any. Also, I didn't say it was shorter, that was somebody else.

Comment: @Ouroborus My mistake. Meant it for David F.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did look into it. Turns out, as you say, the performance difference is negligible even for large tasks. The real difference is in their behaviors. `.indexof(...) >= 0` doesn't respond identically compared to `.includes(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ("abc".includes("a")) console.log("a")
```